# What Does "QUE" means in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, word-request

I was listening a song and repeatedly came across with the word QUE. I am not sure is it name or I don't know what is it?

Can anyone look into this, whenever get a chance?

I am not sure is it OK to mention YouTube link.

**Sample Sentence:**

> I asked my mother, What will I be? Will I be pretty? Will I be rich? Here's what she
> said to me, **`Que`** sera, sera Whatever will be, will be. The future's not
> ours to see

Comment: At the very least you need to tell us the song, and ideally provide some lyrics for us to look at. Very often it's a matter of slang usage, but it's impossible to tell without context.

Comment: I have updated sample sentence. Thank You.

Comment: @fred2 That song is so old. Anyone over about 50 knows it, and plenty of younger folk too.

Comment: _Mad_ magazine used to have little cartoons in the margin by Sergio Aragonés. They often showed people, having fled a cinema showing a Doris Day movie,  vomiting in the gutter.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/que%20ser%C3%A1,%20ser%C3%A1 - (Spanish phrase) what will be, will be

Comment: @ColleenV The saying has no history in Spain, Portugal, Italy, or France, and is ungrammatical in all four Romance languages. It is composed of Spanish or Italian words superimposed on English syntax - a word-for-word mistranslation of English "What will be will be", merging the free relative pronoun what (= "that which") with the interrogative what?

Comment: @Michael Harvey - the OP updated their question. The original question did not include the quote and (unless one guessed the song) was unanswerable. Once the quote was provided it was obviously an extremely easy answer.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey All I did was copy from the dictionary. Take it up with M-W.

Answer (score 4):

"Que sera, sera" is a famous song which quotes a (fictional) Spanish idiom. So the words you're having trouble with are not English. The translation is actually in the song: "What will be, will be". In other words, the song is saying "you can't see the future. Whatever happens, is going to happen regardless, so don't worry about it."

[Wikipedia gives the history of the song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que_Sera,_Sera_(Whatever_Will_Be,_Will_Be)), and how the words are, in fact, not real Spanish, while the idiom's background is in England.